# How to measure the total amount of time my React Native app gets used

Tags: django, react-native

I am about to launch a beta version for my react native application, and I want to get information on how much time users stay on my app, and actually use it, how frequently they enter it etc. That would help giving me feedback. Also could be useful to know which pages get used the most. Is there such a thing that exists for that?

Comment: look at firebase/google analytics.

Answer (score 1):

You may use analytics in your project. Google Firebase provides analytics. But I use [Appcenter](http://appcenter.ms) Analytics for my app. You can add custom events as well to track which page the user has opened or to find whether the button was clicked by user. Here is a screenshot from Appcenter dashboard.

[image]